# Unable to change secret in firebase PHP-JWT

Tags: php, firebase, jwt

I am trying to implement firebase php-jwt, but I am unable to change the "default" secret. When I do so, the JWT can't be decoded properly. I'm storing the generated token in localStorage and ensured it is the same value I get back when trying to decode it. The below code is working fine, but when I want to use any other secret, it doesn't validate anymore.

Setting the token:

```
        $key = 'example_key';
        $payload = [
            "id" => $auth["id"],
            "sub" => $auth["email"],
            "exp" => $issuedAt + 60 * 60,
            "iss" => "mySite",  
            "iat" => $issuedAt, 
        ];

        $token = JWT::encode($payload, $key, 'HS256');
```

Getting the token:

```
 $jwtSecret = 'example_key';
  try {
        $decodedToken = JWT::decode($token,new Key($jwtSecret, 'HS256'));       
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new HttpForbiddenException($request, 'Access denied'.$e);
        }
```